# Testing Windows applications with RIDE Robot Framework and Appium?

Tags: appium, robotframework, windows, ride

I have Robot Framework and the RIDE IDE installed. I have tried the Selenium library with RIDE, and works for testing web interfaces. I now want to test Windows Applications.

Is it possible to test Windows Applications with Appium and RIDE? By writing Robot Framework keywords? Is this [library](https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary) capable of doing that?

I also have WinAppDriver installed. Essentially, I want to mimic [this sample test of the Windows Calculator](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/tree/master/Samples/C%23/CalculatorTest) with Robot Framework and Appium.

There are plenty of examples of tests for mobile applications with Appium, but none for Windows apps that have proven useful so far.

Comment: Appium is aimed at mobile applications. Why not to use the WinAppDriver library itself? It's clear it fits your needs.

Comment: Yes, well, I have tried it by itself with C# code, but the aim is to have non-programmers understand the test cases. So, the simple keywords syntax that Robot Framework offers would be useful in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

[The DesktopLibrary portion of Robotframework-Zoomba](https://github.com/Accruent/robotframework-zoomba) extends AppiumLibrary to support windows applications better. [There is a calculator example using Appium](https://github.com/Accruent/robotframework-zoomba/blob/master/samples/Appium-DesktopTests.robot) or [running on WinAppDriver itself](https://github.com/Accruent/robotframework-zoomba/blob/master/samples/WinAppDriver-DesktopTests.robot).

Some [examples of the features can be found here](https://github.com/Accruent/robotframework-zoomba/blob/master/samples/WinAppDriver-DesktopTests.robot) and the [keyword docs here](https://accruent.github.io/robotframework-zoomba/DesktopLibraryDocumentation.html).